# Where can I ask a technical question about HDMI?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a technical question about [HDMI-CEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control), a feature of HDMI that allows media devices to communicate with each other. Specifically, I'm curious about the technical requirements to implement HDMI-CEC.

> CEC is an an optional feature in the HDMI v1.1 specification ([source](https://www.hdmi.org/learningcenter/kb.aspx?c=3#86)). For existing HDMI devices without CEC, such as the Xbox One, could support for CEC be implemented in a software update? Or would a new hardware revision be needed?

**Is there a site for technical questions about video interfaces like HDMI?**

Comment: From a hardware or software standpoint? It would really depend on the question.

Comment: @TimPost From a hardware standpoint. To better explain my question, HDMI-CEC was introduced in HDMI 1.3. The Xbox One has an HDMI 1.4 port, but does not support CEC. Would CEC support require a new hardware revision?

Comment: CEC is hardware dependent.  Worth pointing out, Consumer Electronics Control, was defined in HDMI 1.0 and was last updated with HDMI 1.3a.  Worth pointing out that while the wiring is mandatory, the implementation of CEC into the product, is optional.  Which means hardware can be designed in such a way where it's impossible to drive the signal low (per the specifications of CEC).  In order to answer this question, it would require somebody, to trace the signal path on the motherboard.  Hence the reason this is a hardware question and not a software question.